# $Tor(A,B) = 0$ if $A,B$ is torsion free

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, tensor-products, bilinear-form, functors

I don't understand the proof given in Hatcher p.265 of $Tor(A,B) = 0$ if $A,B$ is torsion free.

The proof is the following :

[image]

The line I don't get is "This means [...] *can be reduced to* $0$ *by a finite number of application of the definining relations for tensor product*".

Why this should follow from the definition of tensor product, and why only $B$ is involved in this process ? Feels that something is hidden under the radar.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nothing is really hiding. Tensor products are usually defined formally as a certain (gross) quotient, but you can rephrase the definition as saying that two tensors are equal iff they can be shown to be equal by finitely many applications of the relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tensor product of two modules $A$ and $B$ over a commutative ring $R$ is defined :
$$
A \otimes_{R} B:=F(A \times B) / G
$$
where $F(A \times B)$ is the free $R$ -module generated by the cartesian product and $G$ is the $R$ -module generated by the relations below.

1. Distributivity $(v, w) + (v', w) \sim (v + v', w)$ and $(v, w) + (v, w') \sim (v, w + w')$.
2. Scalar multiples $c(v, w) \sim (cv, w)$ and $c(v, w) \sim (v, cw)$.

An example to what hatcher means is the following.
$$2\otimes 1+(-1)\otimes 2=(2-2)\otimes 1=0 \in \mathbb{Z} \bigotimes \mathbb{Z}$$
We used the relations a finite number of times to reduce the sum on the left to $0$. In this case we had to use the elements of $2, 1 \in B=\mathbb{Z}$. In this example $1,2$ generates $B_0$ that in this particuler example is also $\mathbb{Z}$.